# Url Re-Writing When Changing Website

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have a website at present, let us assume www.TheShop.com, which is running on Martjack. Which is a sucky E-Commerce Platform, made in .net. It has a long url structure and the examples can be seen on:

http://www.thebodyshop.in/Products/Skincare-Treatment/TEA-TREE/Tea-Tree-Oil/pid-3368697.aspx

This URL Structure is really complex.

Now I am moving to Prestashop and it has simple url structure.

Question: I need to forward the links of individual products to the new product pages on prestashop. And I could only come up with the following solutions:

1. Individually forward the links (HOW? I HAVE NO IDEA!)
2. Use some module which has been made for prestashop which helps me out.
3. In some way use the pid given at the end of the products for re-routing to the new product pages.
4. 301 Redirect rule can be used, but something else will be more useful as playing with .htaccess is a little risky.

I would like to get suggestions on how to go about the whole situation.

Comment: .htaccess `RewriteRule` looking for the pid is our best bet. Make sure you use `[R=permanent,L]` in the end of your rule.

Comment: RedirectPermanent /index.php?type=store&category=11&subcategory=15&item=67 http://www.example.com/64-white-

Redirect 301 /index.php?type=store&category=11&subcategory=15&item=67 http://www.example.com/64-white-


RedirectRule /index.php?type=store&category=11&subcategory=15&item=67 http://www.example.com/64-white- [L,R=301]

This is an example I could find, but being a novice, I do not exactly understnand what functionality does the [R=permanent,L] do? It signifies Right is the permanent URL for the Left one.

Comment: `[R=permanent,L]` is mainly for SEO so that search engines know that the old url no longer exists and it has been permanently replaced with the new one. `[R=301,L]` is the same thing (301 = permanent)

Comment: Okay Will implement and update. Thanks!